# Dockerfile COPY files not showing on VOLUME

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

So im trying to get Docker adopted in our companies release workflow so i have to produce a project using docker and all tech i want to incorporate.

I have created a Dockerfile to build our VM environment, everything is working fine except the last few steps.

I'll have a folder on my machine with our standardised docker LEMP stack when i build the image for the project it creates a new mounted volume in my /documents/kitematic/image_name which is where we will init a git repo.

for that reason i want to use COPY or add to copy all the dockerfiles into the new Docker volume so it is included in the git repo to track changes, aswell making it easier for devs to just clone the repo build and go.

The last part of the Dockerfile is

```
# Create Mounted Folders
RUN mkdir /$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR && \
mkdir /$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR/www && \
mkdir /$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR/docker_stack

# set owners of web folders before mounting
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# set folder groups
RUN chown -Rf www-data:www-data /$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR

# Mount folders
VOLUME ["/$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR/www","/$SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR/docker_stack/"]

# Expose Ports
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80

# Add git commands to allow container updating
ADD ./docker_stack/pull /usr/bin/pull
ADD ./docker_stack/push /usr/bin/push
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/pull && chmod 755 /usr/bin/push

# Supervisor Config
ADD ./docker_stack/confs/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Start Supervisord
ADD ./docker_stack/start.sh /start.sh

# nginx site conf
RUN rm -Rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/*
ADD ./docker_stack/confs/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/

# Copy docker project to folder for inclusion to GIT repo
ADD ./docker_stack/ /mounted/docker_stack

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]
```

so docker_stack in my local folder is where the docker files are, i was originally using a env var $SMACK_APP_VOL_DIR for the add and read people having issues with envs and ADD/COPY so hardcoded the mount path. it still doesnt move the docker_stack directory over but if i do

```
ADD ./docker_stack/ /home
```

it does copy it to the /home directory but if i try adding /home to VOLUME the files are not displayed in my local machine.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9):

You need to move your `VOLUME` instruction down below your final `ADD` instruction (I'd suggest right above that `CMD` instruction) -- once a directory is defined as a `VOLUME`, it is essentially "snapshotted" at that point, and created empty and fresh for every additional container/layer, so any files added after that point will be obscured/ignored.

It's also worth noting that you don't need to explicitly define the `VOLUME` inside the `Dockerfile` in order to use the bind-mount form of `-v` at runtime, so you probably don't technically need to have the `docker_stack` directory in a `VOLUME` in the `Dockerfile` at all.